# What is the "_path" method in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm learning RoR, and I'm getting very confused by the "_path" method as it's used in Controllers and Routes. To be more specific, I'm referring to the many different calls that take the syntax "(something)_path". So far as I know, they all seem to either encode or manipulate a URL or link. I'm having a hard time mastering the use of this type of method because I can't figure out what it's core functionality is supposed to be.

For example, I could use the following code to redirect an old URL structure to a page of listed Tweet instances in my config/routes.rb file:

```
get '/all' => 'tweets#index', as: 'all_tweets'
```

Only now can I use the following in an .erb file. Notice the "_path" code at the end of the line.

```
<%= link_to "All Tweets", all_tweets_path %>
```

I could also use the following code to create a link to an edit page (and another action) in a different .erb file:

```
<p><%= link_to tweet.user.name, edit_tweet_path(@tweet) %></p>
```

---

I've tried reading through my study materials as well as the RoR documentation, but I always end up more lost than when I began. Does anybody know the low-level definition of this "_path" method?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Helper**

It's called a `route helper`, which means that Rails will generate them to help provide you with resource-based routing structures. I'll explain more in a second

--

To explain properly - Rails is just a framework.

Like all software, it is a series of files loaded in a particular order. As such, Rails creates a series of [*helper* methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html) in the booting process. These "helper" methods can then be used throughout your application to call functionality / information as you require:

> The Rails framework provides a large number of helpers for working
>   with assets, dates, forms, numbers and model objects, to name a few.
>   These helpers are available to all templates by default.
>
> In addition to using the standard template helpers provided, creating
>   custom helpers to extract complicated logic or reusable functionality
>   is strongly encouraged. By default, each controller will include all
>   helpers. These helpers are only accessible on the controller through
>   .helpers

The `route` helpers (which are generated from your `config/routes.rb` file give you the ability to call routes which are *resourceful*. These might seem strange to begin with, but once you understand them, will help you inexorably.

--

**Resourceful**

To give you more clarity - Rails routes are known as *resourceful*

This means they are constructed around *resources*. To give you a brief definition of this, you need to appreciate that the *resources* of your application are the pools of data you can add to, and pull 
from.

To explain further, because Rails is [*object orientated*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). If you're new, this won't mean very much, but keep it in mind, as when you progress through the language / work, you'll begin to see why this is important.

Object orientated programming puts OBJECTS at the center of the flow. Typically, you'd put logic at the center, but with OOP, it's the objects. This is very important for us, as it means that everything you do in Rails is based around the objects you can create.

As per the [MVC principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (which, again, is what Rails is built on), you'll create / invoke your objects from your `Model`s:

[image]

This means that if you want to create a series of routes to "CRUD" (Create Read Update Destroy) your objects, Rails is able to create the routes necessary to do that. This is where the `resources` directives come from inside the routes file:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 20):

Actually, these paths are generated based on your `routes.rb`. If you run this command at your project, you would be able to see all available on your app

```
rake routes
```

For example, if I declare my resources in `routes.rb` like this

```
resources :posts
```

then I would automatically have following available paths

```
posts_path
post_path
new_post_path
edit_post_path
```

If you use some strange `abc_path` which has not been declared in `routes.rb`, then you will get errors.

Hope this is helpful, you will definitely need to work more with Rails and then eventually you will understand all of these things :)

Comment: Thanks so much for making it simple for me. Are those four (list all, show one, create, update) the only four "_path" methods that get created?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. You can try putting `resources :posts` in your routes.rb and run `rake routes` to see how different methods are generated :)

Answer (score 2):

you could find definition for these methods in rails repository:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L127